# RecycleView - No adapter attached, skipping layout in Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Sup guys,

I am currently implementing the ListAdapter for my RecycleView. While implementing I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/simform-engineering/listadapter-a-recyclerview-adapter-extension-5359d13bd879

There is a problem with which I am currently struggeling with:
Code:

```
adapter = UsersAdapter()
rvUsers.adapter = adapter

userListLiveData.observe(this, Observer {list->
    adapter.submitList(list)
})
```

I dont know if I implemented this correctly, because I get the error that the adapter isnt attached.

Here`s my Code:

```
      class InvoiceListAdapter : ListAdapter<InvoiceModel, InvoiceViewHolder>(InvoiceListDiffCallback()) {
       override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): InvoiceViewHolder {
           return InvoiceViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, parent, false))
       }
   
       override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: InvoiceViewHolder, position: Int) {
           holder.bindTo(position)
       }
   
       override fun getItemCount(): Int {
           val count = super.getItemCount()
           return when(count) {
               0 -> 1
               else -> count
           }
       }
   
   }

class InvoiceListDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<InvoiceModel>() {
   override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: InvoiceModel, newItem: InvoiceModel): Boolean {
       return oldItem == newItem
   }

   override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: InvoiceModel, newItem: InvoiceModel): Boolean {
       return oldItem == newItem
   }

}
```

My Fragment:

```
    class FirstFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var invoiceAdapter: InvoiceListAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val items = mutableListOf<InvoiceModel>()
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

        invoiceAdapter = InvoiceListAdapter()

        invoiceList.layoutManager = layoutManager
        invoiceList.adapter = invoiceAdapter


        for (i in 0..40) {
            print(i)
        }

        items.add(
            InvoiceModel(
                "Einkauf",
                "Digital",
                "27.05.2020 12:00 Uhr",
                "Wasser  gekauft",
                null,
                "Portmonaiee",
                true
            )
        )
        invoiceAdapter.submitList(items)
    }
}




Has anyone an idea how to fix that the adapter isnt attached?
```

Comment: is your application getting crashed?

Comment: No, its only shows a white application, like there is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Well you should notify the adapter about the changes in your list. That way they will be shown on the display. You could try with:
invoiceAdapter.notifydatasetChanged()

Or this one:
invoiceAdapter.notifyItemInserted(items.size - 1)

Comment: Where should I add the notifyDatasetChanged? In the fragment or the adapter? And are the inflators correct?

Comment: After submitList

Comment: It doesnt work. Ether with notifyDatasetChanged() or notifyItemInserted(items.size - 1) :( Any other ideas? Are the inflators correct?

Comment: Oh I forgot to say that i have a ViewHolder, which is in the same File like my InvoiceModel and it had a bindTo function in it: 

`
class InvoiceViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun bindTo(invoice: Int) {
        val items = mutableListOf<InvoiceModel>()
        for (i in 0..40) {
            print(i)
        }

        items.add(
            InvoiceModel("Einkauf", "Digital", "27.05.2020 12:00 Uhr", "Wasser  gekauft", null, "Portmonaiee", true)
        )
    }
}
`

Comment: Can you try to attach the adapter in onCreate() method instead of onViewCreated()

Comment: It looks great. But ive got the error message: invoiceList must not be null

Comment: So i did replace that:
        invoiceList.layoutManager = layoutManager
        invoiceList.adapter = invoiceAdapter
with:
        invoiceList?.layoutManager = layoutManager
        invoiceList?.adapter = invoiceAdapter

But now there is the error message again: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: You can try to use 'apply' instead: 

   list_recycler_view.apply {
       layoutManager = layoutManager
      adapter = invoiceAdapter
    }

Comment: I did it in apply but there comes the following error message Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.getContext()' on a null object reference

My code is now: 

        invoiceList.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            adapter = invoiceAdapter
        }

Comment: Instead of 'invoiceList' you should use the id of the RecyclerView in your xml layout file

Comment: Yeah, but the ID of the "invoiceList" is in my xml file invoiceList :D

Comment: I just noticed the updated code. Try to use your variable 'layoutManager' instead of 'LinearLayoutManager(context)' in the 'apply'm to keep access to the context outside of 'apply'

Comment: I edited. My current code is in my fragment: 
`
        var items = mutableListOf<InvoiceModel>()
        var layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

        invoiceAdapter = InvoiceListAdapter()

        invoiceList.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            adapter = invoiceAdapter
        }
`

Comment: Use this instead:  
`var items = mutableListOf<InvoiceModel>() 
var layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context) 
invoiceAdapter = InvoiceListAdapter() 
invoiceList.apply { 
   layoutManager = layoutManager
 adapter = invoiceAdapter } ` 

As i mentioned above - don't try to use 'context' in 'apply'

Comment: If I do your code the app crashs instant with Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference


        var items = mutableListOf<InvoiceModel>()
        var layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        invoiceAdapter = InvoiceListAdapter()

        invoiceList.apply {
            layoutManager = layoutManager
            adapter = invoiceAdapter
        }

Comment: The current code looks like this: https://gyazo.com/0a1420b0ff4c81ad5d5127867a7495f3

Comment: So if you use 'apply', as we do now, put the code back to 'onViewCreated()' and it should work

Comment: Alright, if I move to code as provided in the screenshot: 
Then the IDE throws:https://www.bilder-upload.eu/bild-8ca285-1593544957.png.html (Gyazo didnt work at the moment)
1. E/RecyclerView: No layout manager attached; skipping layout 

Could i contact you on Discord? 
My Discordtag is: Trite#8657